# How to mock super class by Mockito / PowerMockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

Here is a `MySQLDAO` class type of T. `insert` method inserts data to the MySQL database.

```
package com.so.examples;

import java.util.List;

public class MySQLDAO<T> {

    public void insert(List<T> data){
        System.out.println("MySQLDAO.insert()");
    }
}
```

and `Users` class that extends `MySQLDAO` class.

```
package com.so.examples;

import java.util.List;

public class Users extends MySQLDAO<User> {

    public void insert(List<User> data){
        System.out.println("Users.insert()");
        data.remove(0);
        data.remove(0);
        super.insert(data);
    }
}
```

`User` class:

```
package com.so.examples;

public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I wanted to know how to mock super `MySQLDAO` class, so that it inserts data to the SQLite database.

And here is a test class itself:

```
package com.so.examples;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyObject;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doAnswer;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.methodsDeclaredIn;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier.suppress;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MySQLDAO.class})
public class UsersTest {

    private Users users;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        suppress(methodsDeclaredIn(MySQLDAO.class));
        users = spy(new Users());
    }

    @Test
    public void mockSuperClass() throws Exception {

        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
            for (Object argument : arguments) {
                System.out.println("argument = " + argument);
            }
            return null;
        }).when((MySQLDAO<User>) users).insert(anyObject());

        List<User> data = Arrays.asList(new User(1, "John"), new User(2, "Smith"),
                new User(3, "Alex"));
        users.insert(data);

        List<User> result = Arrays.asList(new User(3, "Alex"));

        Mockito.verify((MySQLDAO<User>) users).insert(result);
    }
}
```

I tried already suppressing methods, but it is not what I want. And I also tried to mock `MySQLDAO` `insert` method by `doAnswer(...)`. This is not working either.

I want to print test:

```
argument = [User{id=3, name='Alex'}]
```

not

```
argument = [User{id=1, name='John'}, User{id=2, name='Smith'}, User{id=3, name='Alex'}]
```

I need to mock super class or replace super class with mocked one. Is it possible by PowerMockito?

Comment: The real question is why?.

Comment: The answer is before inserting `Users` should make some modifications with `List<User>`. It may remove some data from the list.

Comment: Then why dont you directly check the size/content of the passed list after the call

Comment: I can solve this problem by changing the design of my code, but I just wanted to know if it is possible mock superclass.